# Exit Feedback Popup when someone click on tab "x"

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Can someone help me with a JavaScript code to show an exit popup when someone clicks on tab "x" to leave that specific page/or website only. (not asking about intent exit pop up). I need to take the userfeedback on my order form to find out if he is happy with the prices. I want to integrate it with contact form 7. Using wordpress. Asking it after 5 hours of search around web.

Thorough help is appreciated.

Comment: use beforeunload event

Comment: yes, i did infact, I used the codes available on here on different pages. Its giving alert only. I need to show a feedback form, instead of alert...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the beforeunload event (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) :

```
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
       alert('Exit site')
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the beforeunload event to show a form

```
 $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
       $('.feedbackform').show();
  });
```

on close of the feedbackform you close the page